# How to create custom header link

Tags: magento2

How to create custom header Link any one suggest me thanks in advance.I used many  tutorial but does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you achieve this using default.xml ( Try below code )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current"  name="name-of-your-header-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Header Link</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path of your header link</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
       </body>
</page>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="ProgrammingAtKstark_CatewithimgWidget" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>

Comment: <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Dckap_Newlink',
    __DIR__
);

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
<route id="newlink" frontName="newlink">
<module name="Dckap_Newlink" />
</route>
</router>
</config>

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
<move element="test-link" destination="header.links"/>
<block class="Dckap\Newlink\Block\Header" name="test-link" after="my-account-link"/>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>

Comment: <?php
namespace Dckap\Newlink\Block;
class Header extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
protected $_template = 'Dckap_Newlink::link.phtml';
public function getHref()
{
return__( 'testuser');
}
public function getLabel()
{
return __('Test Link');
}
}
?>

Comment: <li>
<a <?php echo $block->getLinkAttributes() ?>><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel())?>
<?php echo($block->getCounter()) ? '<span>' . $block->escapeHtml($block->getCounter()) . '</span>' : ''; ?>
</a>
</li>

Comment: i want to call above module  in our header for custom header lonk page open

Answer (score 0):

Add below code

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custome-link" >
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">your-label</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">your-link-path</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, configure and register your custom module. Then create default.xml file in app/code/Magenticians/Mymodule/view/frontend/layout and paste the following code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
     <referenceBlock name="header.links">
         <block class="Magenticians\Mymodule\Block\Link" name="custom-header-link">
             <arguments>
     <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</argument>
     <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">contact</argument>
     </arguments>
         </block>
     </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Now Create Link.php file in app/code/Magenticians/Mymodule/Block and paste the following code in it:

```
<?php
namespace Magenticians\Mymodule\Block;

class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
/**
* Render block HTML.
*
* @return string
*/
protected function _toHtml()
    {
     if (false != $this->getTemplate()) 
     {
     return parent::_toHtml();
     }
     return '<li><a ' . $this->getLinkAttributes() . ' >' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getLabel()) . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

At last just run these commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```